# sl4a python make a Toast for android phone

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, sl4a

I wrote only this 3 lines in python using [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/):

```
    import android
    droid = android.Android()
    droid.makeToast(u"ascc4r")
```

When this code runs, I get the following error:

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tibi\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\eclipse\plugins        \org.python.pydev_2.8.2.2013090511\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1446, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Users\Tibi\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\eclipse\plugins    org.python.pydev_2.8.2.2013090511\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1092, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Tibi\workspace\26\src\26module.py", line 7, in <module>
    droid = android.Android()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\android.py", line 34, in __init__
   self.conn = socket.create_connection(addr)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\socket.py", line 547, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Environment setup:
    - Python 2.6.6
    - set ap_port=9999
    - adb forward tcp:9999 tcp:xxxx (xxxx where I started the server on the phone)
My android.py is in the Python/Lib folder.

Update:
I tried this 3 instruction in CMD and it's work, making a Toast. So I think the fault is in the ADT bundle, or Eclipse Python plugin.

What is this Errno 11001?

Comment: Try using the sl4a module instead (import sl4a).

Answer (score 2):

> What is this Errno 11001?

I don't know about that error, but I suggest to use the correct syntax which is

```
 import android
 droid = android.Android()
 droid.makeToast('my text to print should be inside the quotes')
```

see also the [API Overview](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/AndroidFacadeAPI)